# When not use Modman?

Tags: security, development, modman

When should one not use Modman in Magento development?

What are the dangers of activating Symlincs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symlinks are not risky and i recommend you to use modman. Only the Magento Core itself can not be deployed with modman through symlinks. You have to use the deployment mode "copy" instead, otherwise you will get troubles with the file `app/Mage.php`.

However, on remote webserver, during deployment you have to deploy all of your modman modules which can take a little bit longer as when you only checkout your git branch. In addition, before deployment, be sure to remove old symlinks.